# Have Javascript call launch modal from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a C# webforms application that has a datatable with edit buttons. The edit button I have launches an alert window with the row ID. However, I need to launch my modal instead of the alert box.
Here is my C# page_load event:

```
                // Initialization.
            string reqVal = this.Request.QueryString["id"];
            string regName = "Jfunc" + reqVal;
            string alert = "alert('Row ID = " + reqVal + "');";

            // Javascript Call.
            this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), regName, alert, true);
```

Ajax is used to retrieve the data from a method. Here is the code for activating the action Edit button:

```
myFormData.Action = "<a class='btn btn-warning' href='Default.aspx?id=" + myFormData.UserID + "'><i class=\"fa fa-pencil - square\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a>";
```

Also, how can I assign an ID name to the edit buttons in my datatable? They should all have the same ID.

Comment: I found part of the solution by using this: `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);` in the page load event. and this in my JavaScript file: `function ShowPopup() {
    $("#btnLaunchModal").click();
    var id = $(this).data('id');` However, the id variable doesn't capture the Row ID. See original post. Also, this takes care of the need to assign an ID to each edit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution. Use Javascript to clicks the LaunchModal button:

```
                // Page Load.
        string reqVal = this.Request.QueryString["id"];
        string regName = "Jfunc" + reqVal;
        string alert = "alert('Row ID = " + reqVal + "');";

        // Javascript Call.
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowModal();", true);
```

And Javascript:

```
function ShowModal() {
$("#btnLaunchModal").click();
var id = getUrlVars()["id"];...

function getUrlVars() {
var vars = [], hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
return vars;
}
```